# Haskell: Elegant solution for integer parsing

Tags: string, parsing, haskell

I want to write a function that gets the first integer in a string, if the integer is at the beginning of the string and is followed by space or nothing.

For example, "12" and "12 kids" would be valid strings, but "12kids", "a12" are invalid.

This is my function:

```
getFirstInteger :: String -> Int
getFirstInteger []                                      = error "No integer"
getFirstInteger str
  | dropWhile (Char.isNumber) str == []                 = read str :: Int
  | Char.isSpace $ head $ dropWhile (Char.isNumber) str = read (takeWhile (Char.isNumber) str) :: Int
  | otherwise                                           = error "No integer found"
```

The problem is that if the string is actually an integer, `head` will raise an exception, so that is why the first condition exists. Is there any elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to parse strings without using parser combinator libraries or any of the machinery in Text.Read, have a look at the functions `break` and `span`:

```
span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

The nice thing is that both of these functions not only return what they match but also the remainder of the string allowing you to continue your parsing.

To solve your problem:

```
import Data.Char

getFirstInteger :: String -> Maybe Int
getFirstInteger str
   let (digs, rest1) = span isDigit str
       endsok = case rest1 of
                  [] -> True
                  (c:_) -> c == ' '
   in
   if not (null digs) && endsok
     then Just (read digs)
     else Nothing          -- either no digits or doesn't end properly
```

This version does not allow a leading minus sign. This next version allows an optional leading minus sign for the integer:

```
getFirstInteger' str =
  let (minus,rest1) = span (=='-') str
      (digs, rest2) = span  isDigit rest1
      endsok = case rest2 of
                 [] -> True
                 (c:_) -> c == ' '
  in
  if length minus <= 1 && not (null digs) && endsok
    then Just (read (minus ++ digs))
    else Nothing
```

Yes - this does not terminate as early as possible on bad input. I provide it mainly as an example of how to chain together calls to `span` and `break`.

Answer (score 4):

```
getFirstInteger :: String -> Int
getFirstInteger = read . head . words
```

`words` will split the `String` into a list of `Strings`, which were originally separated by whitespace. `head` will take the first (or `error` if the original string was empty), and `read` will parse the string as usual (and `error` if the first word wasn't a valid `Int`).

However, I prefer a variant that doesn't use `error` on empty `String`s or unparseable ones, e.g.

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

getFirstInteger :: String -> Maybe Int
getFirstInteger [] = Nothing
getFirstInteger xs = readMaybe . head . words $ xs
```

One could write this completely point-free with `listToMaybe` from `Data.Maybe`, but that's probably an overkill:

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Control.Monad ((>=>))

getFirstInteger :: String -> Maybe Int
getFirstInteger = listToMaybe . words >=> readMaybe
```

Comment: I have a question regarding `read`. How do I use the parsing value? `read` is called like this `read str :: Type`, but your function `getFirstInteger` gives me a parse error since it doesn't have the type mentioned. If I write in Prelude `(read . head . word) "a12" :: Int`, it also gives me an error.

Comment: @RazvanMeriniuc: your example says that `"12kids"` isn't a valid string, so an error is expected in `"a12"`. Note that the type you expect from `read` is non-ambiguous due to `getFirstInteger`'s type signature.

Answer (score 2):

Use `reads`. For example:

```
type Unit = String

readUnit :: String -> Maybe (Int, Maybe Unit)
readUnit s = case reads s of               -- the integer is at the beginning of the string and...
    (n, ' ':unit):_ -> Just (n, Just unit) -- is followed by space...
    (n, ""      ):_ -> Just (n, Nothing)   -- or nothing.
    _ -> Nothing
```

In ghci:

```
> readUnit "12"
Just (12,Nothing)
> readUnit "12 kids"
Just (12,Just "kids")
> readUnit "12kids"
Nothing
> readUnit "a12"
Nothing
```

However, there are a few minor considerations to keep in mind. It's possible that `read` does not restrict the syntax as much as you might want; for example, the following answer may surprise you:

```
> readUnit "  ((-0x5)) kids"
Just (-5,Just "kids")
```

You may also want to drop extraneous spaces in the unit; for example, you could change the first clause above to

```
(n, ' ':unit):_ -> Just (n, Just (dropWhile isSpace unit))
```

or similar. And as a final variation on this theme, note that while the standard instances of `Read` never return lists with more than one element from `reads`, it is technically possible that some user-supplied type may do so. So if you were ever to use `reads` to parse types other than `Int`, you may want to either demand an unambiguous parse or consider all the parses before deciding what to do; the above code bakes in the assumption that the first parse is as good as any.

Comment: Given the arbitrary amount of whitespace after `12`, you might want to use `lex` instead. Also, I think your patterns should be `[(n, ...)]`, unless you _really_ want to accept ambiguous parsings.

Comment: @Zeta The OP says nothing about arbitrary amounts of whitespace, so I did not assume he wanted to consume arbitrary amounts of whitespace. The standard `Read` instances do not produce ambiguous parses. I considered both of these subtleties while writing this answer. I also considered some you didn't mention; for example, the standard `Read` instance for `Int` will accept some things outside the OP's specification like extra whitespace *before* the number and numbers in parentheses; I judged these to be an acceptable tradeoff for the low code required to implement this solution.

Comment: You already got my upvote before I commented, :D. I was more or less thinking from a teaching perspective. I'm aware of those (let's call them) "quirks", but OP might not. And yes, the tradeoff is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Zeta Yes, good point. I'll add some text to the answer calling out some of these considerations.